# Conditional Probability, help me

Tags: probability

A bag contains some red balls and some blue balls
Probability that first ball is red is 1/3
Probability that second ball is blue is 2/3
Probability that taking out a second red given the first is red ball is 1/5 and probability taking out a second blue ball given the first is blue is 3/5. Find number of balls of each colour.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a shuffled deck of cards, the probability of drawing an ace on your first pick is $4/52$. The probability of drawing one on your second pick (without replacing the first card in the deck) is $4/51$ if the first card wasn't an ace, and $3/51$ if it was. Notice how the numerator and denominator change when you sample the deck, and depending on the outcome?

Can you notice a similar change of probabilities in your original problem? Note that $1/3 = 2/6$ and $2/3 = 4/6$.

Comment: @rasr, no problem! If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick box left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've solved it. But there are 2 red and 4 blue balls. You can try working backwards and get the working out. As previously mentioned from other users, you could notice the numerator and denominator.